# Generate HASH (Unique Random) from String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, random, parse-platform

I am using `Parse` (www.parse.com) as backend in one of my project.

I would like to generate unique random (`Promocode`) by applying the current date and time every time in Java script. The random should be readable alphabets / numbers.

I know the the random generation process by searching in Google. But I am not sure whether this is unique always. So to check that, every time i have to contact the backend, whether any already existing random which matched to the current one. It is being a long process. Since I require this process to do at sign up process, I need a better solution for this.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Why is contacting backend such a long process? It should not take more than 500ms, I guess.

Comment: So what do you actually want I am not clear.

You want to keep an in-memory copy of already existing "unique numbers" through which you can check that whether the one's that you generate do not already exist in the copy. Am I understanding you correctly ?

Comment: @WojciechFrącz: Consider there is repeated 3 calls going and coming as it is duplicating the random 3 times (It may happen if DB sizes increases day by day), it will be annoying for the users who is coming to sign up.

Comment: @SameerSawla, I am looking for a solution that gives more than 95% surety for unique random code. Since it is a promo code feature, the random should be human readable (5 to 10 characters).

Answer (score 0):

What i could understand from your question is that you want a good hash function which ensures that the values are unique every time so you won't have to do the long processing of checking whether the value is unique or already exists.

First let me clear out something, hashing isn't doesn't necessarily mean 'unique' but they are supposed to be 'unique enough'. For the best hashing library in JS, you should check out [crypto.js](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/)

They have different kinds of hashing functions available, take a look at this one:

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/sha256.js"></script>
<script>
    var hash = CryptoJS.SHA256("Message");

    alert(typeof hash); // object

    alert(hash); // 2f77668a9dfbf8d5848b9eeb4a7145ca94c6ed9236e4a773f6dcafa5132b2f91
</script>
```

I mean look at the value generated by that hash function.. the possibility of having a duplicate of that value is extremely extremely slim. So, you can safely use that one or also dig out the library to use the one which you think is the best for you.

Comment: Hi Abdul, Thanks for your response. Actually i have looked Google CryptoJS already. My concern here is, all the algorithm Google provides, gives the long has value (like 16, 32 and so on). Since it is promo code feature, I need it readable random (like 5 to 10 characters). Can you understand my point?

Comment: So every promo code you generate.. you send it back to servers to check if it exists or not?